# SQL: How to display the top 10 list of the users name who has the most item?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and I thought that I will need some help with the basics.

I want to display top 10 users name and the amount of the users friends. How will I do this ?

The top 10 will list out  the user who has the most friends count in descending order But the proble m is I have no clue how to do this with code .

app_id is the user

app_friends_id is the users  friends

```
app_id     app_friends_id 



40          20

40          10

30          30

40          50
```

There are 3 app_id  with 40 , so I want to display   app_id 40 and app_friends_id's total count 3. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: For your vendor RDBMS, Check out the GROUP BY clause and COUNT() and SUM() aggregation functions.

Comment: added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax of the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand, you can try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 app_id,COUNT(app_id) as 'count_of_friend' 
FROM table 
GROUP BY app_id 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

the result is:

```
app_id        count_of_friend
   40                3
   30                1
```

Comment: How can I display the app_id 40 and app_friends_id count of 3 ?

Comment: This looks good but error still pops up. For example how will I do  if I want to display app_id and count_of_friends from a table named app_friends? And sorry to say this but what is the TOP 10 after the SELECT?

Comment: you're looking for top 10 users and `top 10` after select means that, i can't understand your problem, this will do what you want, and you can remove `TOP 10` to return all of rows

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how your database is set up, since friends tables can be a little "weird," but you probably want to do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 app_id, COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY app_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

On the other hand, if your table is set up where both columns reference potentially reference the same users in no particular order (which I suspect is the case), you'd probably want to union it against itself with the use of a CTE. This is assuming you're using SQL Server. In MySQL, you could just do a nested query with similar contents.

```
; WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP 10 app_id AS [user], COUNT(*) AS [count]
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY app_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP 10 app_friends_id AS [user], COUNT(*) AS [count]
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY app_friends_id
)

SELECT TOP 10 [user], SUM([count])
FROM cte
GROUP BY [user]
ORDER BY SUM([count]) DESC
```